# Get predictions from each tree in a random forest model in R (using train function in training and predict in predicting)

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I am using a `train` function in training a Random Forest model:

```
fitControl = trainControl(method="oob")
tuneGrid = expand.grid(.mtry=c(15))    

rfmod = train(p ~   
            x +  
            y +   
            z,             
          method="rf",
          data=train_df,
          tuneGrid=tuneGrid,
          trControl=fitControl,
          importance=TRUE,
          allowParallel=TRUE)
```

This is a simplified code showing the structure of my model and I am using the training data `train_df`.

And I want to have the prediction from each tree. I searched somehow and tried this:

```
preds <- predict(rfmod, newdata = test_df[1], predict.all = TRUE)
```

I just used the first row of my test data `test_df`. After this, when I check `preds` it just still gives me only one prediction value, while I want the prediction from all the trees.

How can I do this to get all the predictions from all the trees?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: try  `randomForest:::predict.randomForest(rfmod$finalModel, test_df, predict.all = TRUE)`. If you would like a more detailed answer please post reproducible code.